# generated select does fire alert on change

Tags: jquery, html-select, alert, onchange

I have a generated select field with 2 options like this

```
<div class="PlentyFormContainer">
    <div class="PlentyFormContainer ArticleAttrTd_0 PlentyWebAttributeTitle">Rollen/Gleiter</div>
    <div class="PlentyFormContainer ArticleAttrTd_1 PlentyWebAttributeSelect">
        <select onchange="  this.blur();
                            switchImage(this.value ,'378_0', '378', aAttribute_Image_Values_378);
                            priceChangeOnMarkup(this.value, '2', '0', 'price_dynamic_0_378', aAttribute_Markup_Values_378, aCurrent_Markups_378, oldPrice_378);
                            "
                class="ArticleAttrSelect PlentyAttributeSelect_1" id="attr_row_0_378_2"
                name="ArticleAttribute[0][378][53]"><option value="" class="PlentyAttributeOption">-- bitte wählen --</option><option  value="1364" class="PlentyAttributeOption PlentyAttributeOption_1364">Rolle weich gebremst für harte Böden&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option  value="1363" class="PlentyAttributeOption PlentyAttributeOption_1363">Rolle hart gebremst für Teppichboden&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
                </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This whole div-select thing is generated by these elements:

```
<div class="plentyAttributeSelectWrapper">
   <div class="plentyAttributeSelectWrapperTitle"><span>Rollen/Gleiter</span>
   </div>
   <div class="plentyAttributeSelectWrapperContent plentyAttributeSelectHasDropdown"> 
      <div>
         <div class="plentyAttributeSelectedValue">
           <span class="plentyAttributeSelectedValueName">Rolle weich gebremst für harte Böden</span>
           <span class="plentyAttributeSelectedValueMarkup plentyAttributeSelectValueMarkup"></span><span class="plentyAttributeSelectedArrow">
           <span></span></span>
           <span class="clear"></span>
         </div>
        <div class="plentyAttributeSelectListWrapper">
         <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="plentyAttributeSelectValue">
               <a><span class="plentyAttributeSelectValueName">Rolle hart gebremst für Teppichboden</span>
              <span class="plentyAttributeSelectValueMarkup"></span></a>
           </div>
         </li>
         <li>
            <div class="plentyAttributeSelectValue">
               <a><span class="plentyAttributeSelectValueName">Rolle weich gebremst für harte Böden</span>
              <span class="plentyAttributeSelectValueMarkup"></span></a>
            </div>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I try to force an alert on changing the the option, there is no reaction.

Comment: For starters, it looks like you have the blur on the actual select element instead of the options. That is probably something you don't want. Secondly, I would move the blur event handler to a separate js file instead of having it inline like you do.

Answer (score 1):

Your generated code is fine.

It shows alert, like demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/ww5Rr/

```
<select onchange="this.blur(); alert('hi! \nAlert is working...');" >
```

Maybe the functions that you call, not posted here, have something broken inside that prevents your alert to show up.

Try putting the alert just after the blur() call.

Answer (score 0):

i try to grab the select with jquery:

```
$('div.PlentyFormContainer select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```